New-ish Midea dryer: very noisy during operation
This started after the dryer was moved out of the way and replaced to allow installation of a new washer.
It is loud, even with the bathroom door closed the whole house hears it.
The unit is not touching the wall. The noise is coming from within the machine.
What would the process be to diagnose or repair this?
https://youtube.com/shorts/U_6RvHYhrCs?feature=share

Is it now touching the wall, when it wasn't before? If so, move it to restore that space.

@keshlam No, it is not touching the wall. I will revise the OP

Designing a laundry area to minimize how much vibration is couples into the structure would be home improvement. We've been inconsistent on whether we answer questions about maintaining major appliances or not.

Sounds like something has been damaged / come loose when the machine was moved. The only option, IMO, is for someone (who knows what they are doing) to open it up whilst running to see exactly where the vibration is coming from.
